# Use delegate methods when using multiple tableviews in a view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I want to use 3 tableviews in a single `ViewController`. The problem is how can I use `UITableViewDelegate` methods seperately. For example; I can use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method seperately for each `UITableView` by tagging. But, I have no idea about using `numberOfRowsInSection` or `numberOfSectionsInTableView` methods for each tableview differently. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make 3 `UITableView` variables in **YourViewController.h**:

```
YourViewController : UIViewController
{
    UITableView* tableView1;
    UITableView* tableView2;
    UITableView* tableView3;
}
```

**YourViewController.m:**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == tableView1)
    {
        //Your code
    }
    if (tableView == tableView2)
    {
        //Your code
    }
    if (tableView == tableView3)
    {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use only one dataSource and Delegate methods for all tables with Conditions inside the datasource and delegate methods.

```
       - (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
      {
     return 1;
     }
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section;
   {
if (tableView==tabl1) {
        return [arr1 count];
}
if (tableView==tabl2) {
        return [arr2 count];

}
if (tableView==tabl3) {
        return [arr3 count];
}
return 0;

   }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
}
if (tableView==tabl1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
if (tableView==tabl2) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [arr2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
if (tableView==tabl3) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [arr3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use separate delegate methods. Instead in each delegate method like `cellForRowAtIndexPath` , you should identify your table as

```
if(tableview == TableView1) 
{ 

}
else if(tableview == TableView2)
{

}
else
{

}
```

and so on . This is the right approach as which ever table u operate will have common delegate methods and then you need only specify the name of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Of course:

All tableview delegate functions have the tableView as the first parameter, so all you have to do is keep track of the three table views and in each delegate function check which table view the delegate call was for:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView == firstTableView) {
    ...
    }
    else if (tableView == secondTableView) {
    ...
    }
    else if (tableView == thirdTableView) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create three table view controller classes, (in case, that every tableview has a bit of complexity involved in their cell display logic). Add them as `[self addChildViewController:(Your Controller Class)` and then next line `[self.view addSubview:(Your Controller Class' view)]` with the view adjusted to frame that you want to set.

Answer (score 1):

See This tutorial might be helpful to you  http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/a-tableview-based-menu-for-ipad/

Answer (score 0):

In all delegate and datasource methods, the first parameter is a reference to the tableview object.  So you can always distinguish among your tableviews.

Answer (score 0):

In `ViewController.h`

```
{
    NSArray *arr1;
    NSArray *arr2;
    NSArray *arr3;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tbl1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tbl2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tbl3;
```

Don't forget to connect this Properites with `XIB's` UITableView instances.

In `ViewController.m`

```
@synthesize tbl1, tbl2, tbl3;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == tbl1)
        return [arr1 count];
    if (tableView == tbl2)
        return [arr2 count];
    if (tableView == tbl3)
        return [arr3 count];
    return 0;
}
```

I hope I helped you.