# Two Tables in a single interface controller not working in WatchKit

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I am trying to put two tables in a single interface controller in WatchKit, I am not able to populate the data in the second table but if I make second table as first table in UI than second table which becomes first is getting populated but not the other one. Any idea what could be the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your delegates use check your tableview for which it is calling then populate data.

Comment: show your code please ....

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the same even if you are doing it from WatchKit.

First, you need to be set both the delegates to this interface controller either from code or from your storyboard.  Once that's done, for every datasource or delegate function you need to identify which tableview is calling it and take actions from there.

Here's a similar post that should help you.
[Multiple UITableview in Single Viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195660/multiple-uitableview-in-single-viewcontroller)