# How to load data from a web service in a NOT UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

**Hi guys**

I'm currently building an app that will have a UITableView that will get it's data from a web service.

this is what I have:

First,  i have a UIViewController that consume data from a web services
that UIViewController has a UITableView to display data, this UIViewController works well.

Second, in each cell from the UITableView i have another UITableView showing information related to the cell pressed,

as you can see in this pic:

[image]

pls see the image

third, i made a custom UITableView Class for display that informacion, it needs information from the  cell to get the data from web services.

My Question is:

How it is made to load data into that UITableView if I have already overwritten the necessary methods to load data into the UIViewController?

**Pls Help me :C**

Comment: The delegate and datasource of UITableView need not be the `UIViewController`, you can use any object which conforms to corresponding protocol.

Comment: i do that, but How do I pass data to the table if I am creating it from the stroyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To respect MVC design pattern, I would advise to set your `UIViewController` as delegate of your tableview inside your tableview cell. This can be done in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like this:

```
cell.tableView.delegate = self;
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195660/multiple-uitableview-in-single-viewcontroller) explains how you can handle 2 table views from within single view controller.