# How to create Sections in Cell in Table View?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating Receipt view, for this i am using tableview. I have created multiple cell to achieve this functionality.

Here is my code to use multiple cell:

```
if indexPath.section == 4    {
    let cell:ProductSummaryTitleCell = self.tblCategorySummary.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProductSummaryTitleCell") as! ProductSummaryTitleCell
    //set the data here
    return cell
}
```

and here is my screenshot what i exactly want in my tableview.

[![Receipt View][1]][1]

Data Structure

```
(
    {
    Amount = "39.5";
    Numbers = 5;
    Productname = "BLACK PEPPER CHICKEN";
    Upgrade = 0;
    UpgradeCount = 0;
    "product_id" = 53;
},
    {
    Amount = "10.9";
    Numbers = 1;
    Productname = "WHOLE SPRING CHICKEN";
    Upgrade = 0;
    UpgradeCount = 0;
    "product_id" = 60;
})
```

this is my category response

```
[
"category_type": mc,
"deleted_date": 0000-00-00 00:00:00,
"created_date": 2015-11-19 21:34:40,
"category_name": chicken,
"company_id": 1,
"category_invoice_name": Chicken,
"Ids": 358,
"updated_by": 2,
"category_icon_image": baa8ae5668029596f6efd9dc00d4c11f.png,
"created_by": 2,
"category_description": chicken,
"update_date": 2016-06-20 22:04:47,
"take_away_price": 0.5,
"branch_id": 1,
"parent_category": 0,
"set_menu": 1,
"pos_id": 6,
"category_status": 1,
"category_image": 6751d0f61304080148b79530d33c5735.png,
"is_deleted": 0,
"category_id": 11
]
```

I am able to do Category summary.
But in product summary you can see there are sections.

I am using only one tableview.
How i can create section for particular cell?
I take one cell of Product Summary.
I want only sections in this cell.
I want to create product summary according to screenshot.

Comment: You might find it useful to look at this recent discussion, which explains how to nest a table view inside a table view cell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell

Comment: Can you show how your data array looks like?

Comment: @Mr.Bista i updated question with array structure of products which i want to display.each category contains this data

Comment: Are your sure that its the full data information? Because I do not see anything, that separates _Category Summary_, _Product summary(Sub Category: Chicken, Fish etc.)_

Comment: @Mr.Bista done.plz check is this sufficient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UITableViewHeader` for the category summary and `Sections` for the product summary. Also take care to use

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("your_cell_identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCellClassName
```

rather than `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("your_cell_identifier")`. The latter is found to be error prone at times.

Comment: i am getting height issue when i use two tableview.

Comment: you needn't use two `UITableViews`. Rather the sections of the same can be made use of.

Comment: i have also one view above category summary

Comment: Okey. Then could you add a mockup of the whole list?

Comment: its just one view bro.

Comment: fine. is it a normal `UIView` or do you need it to be loaded in the `UITableview`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125893/discussion-between-krutarth-patel-and-mathews).

Comment: get an understanding of the UI part from [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8M2R4m7aLSNUWtKaTd5RVZLbTg/view?usp=sharing). But you must work on the data structures for processing the response

Answer (score 1):

> In a single tableview show the "Category Summary" as tableview header
>   and "Product Summary" you can use the section and cells.

Please below image you will get an idea.

[image]

> Also you can try by considering the following options (If Category Summary is dynamic):

[image]

Comment: can i use tableview cell as header and footer of tableview?

Comment: I think probably you can, because it is nothing but the UIView itself..

Comment: agree.but in category summary you can see category is  dynamic.check below category there is amountview. amountview is fix.it will also loop with array if i take in headerview

Comment: Yes, your category summaries are dynamic, Ok wait i will modify my answer

Comment: category name is dynamic and totalview is fix

Comment: can you give a try to add a tableview header view with tableview? see if it work..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125605/discussion-between-suhas-patil-and-krutarth-patel).